# What's My.Computer.Network.UploadFile behavior on duplicate filename?

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I have been given a program that uploades pdf files to an ftp server, which is something I never did. I've been asked what the behavior regarding attempting to upload a duplicate filename is. It apparently doesnt check for duplicate filenames manually, but the comand that uploads the file is My.Computer.Network.UploadFile and I can't find what happens when attempting to upload a duplicate file anywhere, does it throw an exception or overwrites the file?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `My.Computer.Network.UploadFile` is a wrapper around [`WebClient.UploadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx), and the documentation for that states:

> This method uses the STOR command to upload an FTP resource.

In the FTP [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) it says (I highlighted the relevant part):

> STORE (STOR)
>
> This command causes the server-DTP to accept the data
> transferred via the data connection and to store the data as
> a file at the server site.  **If the file specified in the
> pathname exists at the server site, then its contents shall
> be replaced by the data being transferred.**  A new file is
> created at the server site if the file specified in the
> pathname does not already exist.

So, if everything is following standards (and that part of RFC 959 hasn't been replaced, I didn't dig further!), then it should replace the existing file.  However, **it is possible for the server to deny overwriting of existing files**, so the behavior is not guaranteed.

Of course, the best thing to do would be to try it out in your environment and see what it does.

Comment: @CodeCaster Great point, thanks.  I added that to the answer, but if it can be made cleared, please feel free to edit or suggest clarifications.